# create resource-file for localization out of txt-file dynamically within the code

Tags: wpf, dynamic, localization, resourcedictionary

my app has to be multilingual, so i created some resource-files which hold the texts e.g.:

```
texts.resx
texts.en.resx
texts.fr.resx
```

that works all fine so far.

but some of the texts are generated with an external tool. i end up with a normal text-file (*.txt) which holds the strings like that:

```
key|language1|language2|language3
```

so what i need to do is read that file at the start and generate the according resource-files.

**what i did so far:**

reading the file with a `StreamReader` and filling lists with the keys and the languages

```
line = reader.ReadLine();
char[] delimiterChars = { '|' };
string[] parts = line.Split(delimiterChars);
keyList.Add(parts[0]);
language1List.Add(parts[1]);
language2List.Add(parts[2]);
```

generating the resource-files:

```
using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter("test.resx"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keyList.Count; i++)
    {
        resx.AddResource(keyList[i], language1List[i]);
    }
}
using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter("test.en.resx"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keyList.Count; i++)
    {
        resx.AddResource(keyList[i], language2List[i]);
    }
}
```

getting a string from the resource-file:

```
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet("test.resx"))
{
    Text = resxSet.GetString(keyList[0]);
}
```

that works all fine.

**the questions**

1. how do i change the language? if i set the culture, the programm "magically" takes the right resource-file, but not the right generated one. when i change it to `("text.en.resx")` it obviously works.
2. how can i access the strings from the view? during design-time, the resource-files don't exist, so i get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got a solution:
generating the resource-files:

```
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("test.resx");
for (int i = 0; i < keyList.Count; i++)
{
    writer.AddResource(keyList[i], language1List[i]);
}
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("test.en.resx");
for (int i = 0; i < keyList.Count; i++)
{
    writer.AddResource(keyList[i], language2List[i]);
}
```

this creates `*.resources` instead of `*.resx` files. they can be read like that:

```
ResourceManager rm = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("test", location, null);
Text = rm.GetString("foo");
```

depending on the set culture, the `ResourceManager` reads the right file and gets the correct text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't understand process of localization...

Answer 1:
When you change language on your computer in Control Panel, program will try to find folder with name of selected language ("en" for english) in your bin and that folder should contain .satellite.dll files (those are files that will be loaded when you select right language). They are generated using english resource strings.

Answer 2:

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
        private static MyProjResources resource = new MyProjResources();

        public MyProjResources Resources
        {
            get
            {
                return resource;
            }
        }
}
```

and you access it like,

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <localization:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Resources.MyProj_EXPORT_PDF, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Height="Auto" Width="200" "></Button>
```

You should consider reading a little bit more on this subject.

Comment: i set the culture like that: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");` and that works fine with the resource-files included in the project itself. but i have to make some more resource-file out of a txt-file. can you post an example on that maybe?